# Why is my anchor tag in Thymeleaf is not redirecting to the local file

Tags: thymeleaf, anchor

I am trying to redirect to another local web page using `a` tag in `Thymeleaf` and `Spring boot` but it is
not working. I am redirecting from `index.html` to `addEdit.html` which are in the same folder.

Here is my code.

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
          <p th:text="${message}"></p>
          <a th:href="@{/addEdit.html}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Add Employee</a> //not working
           <table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
               <thead class="">
                   <tr> 
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Departmen</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                         <th></th>
                         <th></th>
                       
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               
               <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="employee : ${employees}" >
                         <th th:text="${employee.id}"></th>
                         <td th:text="${employee.name}"></td>
                         <td th:text="${employee.department}"></td>
                         <td th:text="${employee.position}"></td>
                         <td>
                             <form action="delete">
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-outline-warning"/>
                             </form>
                         </td>
                          <td>
                             <form action="edit">
                                <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-outline-info"/>
                             </form>
                         </td>
                    </tr>
                   
               </tbody>
               
           </table>
          </div>
```

**my EmployeeController**

```
 @Autowired
 private employeeRepo repo;
 
 @RequestMapping("/")
 public String home(Model model) {
     List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<>();
     list = repo.findAll();
     model.addAttribute("employees",list);
     return "index";
 }
 
 @PostMapping("/addEmployee")
 public void addEmployee(Employee employee,Model model) {
     repo.save(employee);
     model.addAttribute("message","Add Successfully");
     home(model);
 }
```

**my addEdit.html**

```
<div class="container bg-light">
      <form action="addEmployee">
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name"><br>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Department" name="department"><br>
            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" placeholder="Position" name="postion"><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Add Employee" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg btn-block">
      </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include the `.html` in your link. The link should point to a URL that your controller exposes. There is currently no controller method that exposes the `/addEdit` url for example.

So update your controller:

```
@GetMapping
public String addEmployee(Model model) {
  // add model attributes here as needed first

  return "addEdit" // This refers to the view, so 'addEdit.html'
}
```

Now update the link to:

```
<a th:href="@{/addEdit}" class="btn btn-outline-info">Add Employee</a>
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. Can you click the check mark next to the answer to indicate this answer fixed the issue?